# Spurious space in Hebrew polyglossia+fontspec

Tags: spacing, xetex, fontspec, polyglossia, hebrew

I use a `tabular` environment with paragraph cells. In one of the cells I include a Hebrew paragraph. The result is that I get a spurious space at the end of the first line (and therefore on the left, since the text starts on the right). I spent a lot of time but couldn't find a solution. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec,polyglossia,amstext}
\setmainlanguage[variant=usmax]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily{\sbl}[Script=Hebrew,Path=./,Extension=.ttf,Scale=1.2]{SBL_Hbrw}

\newenvironment{HEBREW}{\begin{hebrew}\beginR\sbl}{\endR\end{hebrew}}

\def\lineoftwo#1#2{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{.485\textwidth}p{.485\textwidth}@{}}\hskip0pt#1&#2\hfill\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}

\lineoftwo{\begin{HEBREW}בָּר֨וּךְ אַתָּ֤ה יְהֹוָה֙ אֱלֹהֵי֙ יִשְׂרָאֵ֣ל אָבִ֔ינוּ מֵעוֹלָ֖ם וְעַד־עוֹלָֽם׃ לְךָ֣ יְ֠הֹוָ֠ה הַגְּדֻלָּ֨ה וְהַגְּבוּרָ֤ה וְהַתִּפְאֶ֨רֶת֙ וְהַנֵּ֣צַח וְהַה֔וֹד כִּי־כֹ֖ל בַּשָּׁמַ֣יִם וּבָאָ֑רֶץ לְךָ֤ יְהוָה֙ הַמַּמְלָכָ֔ה וְהַמִּתְנַשֵּׂ֖א לְכֹ֥ל ׀ לְרֹֽאשׁ׃ וְהָעֹ֤שֶׁר וְהַכָּבוֹד֙ מִלְּפָנֶ֔יךָ וְאַתָּה֙ מוֹשֵׁ֣ל בַּכֹּ֔ל וּבְיָדְךָ֖ כֹּ֣חַ וּגְבוּרָ֑ה וּבְיָ֣דְךָ֔ לְגַדֵּ֥ל וּלְחַזֵּ֖ק לַכֹּֽל׃ וְעַתָּ֣ה אֱלֹהֵ֔ינוּ מוֹדִ֥ים אֲנַ֖חְנוּ לָ֑ךְ וּֽמְהַֽלְלִ֖ים לְשֵׁ֥ם תִּפְאַרְתֶּֽךָ׃ וַאֲנַ֤חְנוּ ׀\hfill\end{HEBREW}}{Baruch atta adonai eloh^^^^0113 yisra^^^^02beel avinu, me^^^^02bfolam ve^^^^02bfad ^^^^02bfolam. Lecha adonai haggedulla vehaggevura vehattif^^^^02beeret vehannetsa^^^^1e25 vehahod ki chol bash-shamayim uva^^^^02bearets, lecha adonai hammamlacha vehammitnas^^^^0113 lechol lerosh. Veha^^^^02bfosher vehakkavod millefanecha ve^^^^02beatta moshel bakkol uvyadecha kowa^^^^1e25 u\ensuremath{\bar{\text{g}}}vura uvyadecha le\ensuremath{\bar{\text{g}}}addel ul^^^^1e25azze^^^^1e33 lakkol.}

\end{document}
```

In this code, `HEBREW` is the environment that uses the polyglossia `hebrew` environment but also invokes the font and takes care of the right-to-left the direction by using `\beginR` and `\endR`. The command `\lineoftwo` just builds a tabular environment. The font used is SBL Hebrew which can be freely downloaded from https://www.sbl-site.org/Fonts/SBL_Hbrw.ttf

I'm using XeLaTeX. Here is the result I get:

[image]

The spurious space is an interword space (glue) so that it has a different width for every paragraph. It only appears at the first line of the paragraph.

What am I doing wrong?

PS. When I remove the `\hskip0pt` command from inside the `\lineoftwo` command I get a perfect Hebrew first line, but also a spurious vertical skip before the line

[image]

which is far worse. How can I have a perfect first line without the vertical skip?

Comment: I don't get your output in  texlive 2023. Is your texsystem up-to-date?

Comment: side remark: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` doesn't make sense with xelatex, and the hebrew font should imho better be declared as `\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}...`, then polyglossia will manage the changes when the language  changes.

Comment: Dear Ulrike. I tested it on overleaf with TeXLive 2023 and I get the same result. I replaced the `\sbl`by a `\hebrewfont` command in the font definition and removed it from the `HEBREW` environment definition. The result is exactly the same. And I removed the `inputenc`package call, same result. Can you show me what you see?

Comment: well my polyglossia version is 2023/10/01, and overleaf certainly won't have that.

Comment: check if there is a spurious space in gloss-hebrew after \def\proofname{הוכחה}.

Comment: HALLELUYAH !! Ulrike you remain the patron saint of us, ignorant TeX users ! Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue is due to a missing % in old versions, but this has been fixed in more recent versions of polyglossia

Answer (score 1):

Once again, the solution has been provided by Ulrike Fischer. If you have the same problem, go into the file

```
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-hebrew.ldf
```

on line 74, if you see

```
  \def\proofname{הוכחה}
```

then add a percent sign at the end:

```
  \def\proofname{הוכחה}%
```

and all you problems will be solved. I mean the problems related to spurious spaces in Hebrew polyglossia. Thanks Ulrike!

Comment: The bug is fixed in TeX Live 2023.